# Drawing on top of multiple JButtons

Tags: java, jbutton, paintcomponent

So, I have multiple objects of the class Square, which is the subclass of JButton. I have an instance of the class Board, which contains a few instances of Square. What I want to do is when I press one of the buttons (squares), draw a shape (a circle) on top of it. For doing that, I have a boolean variable in the Square class, namely isClicked, that basically decides what has to be drawn in the paintComponent method.

The problem is that buttons start to behave in a weird way when I have a few of them. Surprisingly, if there is only one of them, there is no problem at all. At first, I had thought the problem might be related to threads, however, I put the main code into invokeLater method and that did not help at all.

I saw a solution using BufferedImage, but I would like to see if there is any possibility to solve the problem doing it my way.

Sorry for possibly not perfect English.

Square class:

```
public class Square extends JButton implements ActionListener {

private int number;
private boolean isClicked;

public Square(int x) {
    number = x;
    isClicked = false;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    if (!isClicked) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
    } else {
        System.out.println("EXECUTED for: " + number);
        g2d.drawOval(this.getX(), this.getY(), 100, 100);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    isClicked = !isClicked;
    System.out.println(isClicked + " " + number);
    repaint();
}

}
```

Board class:

```
public class Board extends JPanel {

private static final int BOARD_WIDTH = (int) (TicTacToe.WIDTH * 0.7);
private static final int VERTICAL_LINE_LENGTH = (int) (TicTacToe.WIDTH * 0.5);
private static final int HORIZONTAL_LINE_LENGTH = (int) (TicTacToe.HEIGHT * 0.8);
private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 5;

private Square[] squares;

public Board() {

}

public void addButtons() {
    squares = new Square[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            Square square = new Square(i);
            square.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
            square.addActionListener(square);
            this.add(square);
            squares[i] = square;
            ((GridLayout)this.getLayout()).setHgap(30);
            ((GridLayout)this.getLayout()).setVgap(30);
    }
}

public Square[] getButtons() {
    return squares;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH));
    // Horiztontal lines
    g2d.drawLine(0, TicTacToe.HEIGHT / 3,
            BOARD_WIDTH, TicTacToe.HEIGHT / 3);
    g2d.drawLine(0, 2 * TicTacToe.HEIGHT / 3,
            BOARD_WIDTH, 2 * TicTacToe.HEIGHT / 3);
    // Vertical lines
    g2d.drawLine(BOARD_WIDTH / 3, 0, BOARD_WIDTH / 3,
            TicTacToe.HEIGHT);
    g2d.drawLine(2 * BOARD_WIDTH / 3, 0, 2 * BOARD_WIDTH / 3,
            TicTacToe.HEIGHT);

}
}
```

Main method:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Board board = new Board();
    board.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (WIDTH * 0.7), HEIGHT));
    board.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    board.addButtons();

    GameOptions opt = new GameOptions();
    opt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (WIDTH * 0.3), HEIGHT));


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.add(board);
    frame.add(opt);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `getX()` and `getY()` on the button's drawing code is completely wrong and does not belong. These methods return the location of the button relative to its container, and so while this might work for a button located at the upper left, it will fail for anything else since you'll end up drawing somewhere far away from the button itself, and so many of your drawings will never show.

You'd be much better off not extending JButton but instead simply swapping ImageIcons that display what you want drawn on the JButton. This is much simpler and much more idiot-proof. You set the button's icon by calling `.setIcon(myImageIcon)` on it, passing in the icon of choice.

But if you absolutely wanted to draw on the button, you'd do so without using `getX()` or `getY()`. You'd also probably want to use a JToggleButton as the parent class, since you're toggling state. For example, my MCVE:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawButtonPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int SIDE = 3;
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLACK;

    public DrawButtonPanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(SIDE, SIDE, GAP, GAP));
        setBackground(BG);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIDE * SIDE; i++) {
            // add(new DrawButton1());
            DrawButton2 drawButton2 = new DrawButton2(i);
            AbstractButton button = drawButton2.getButton();
            add(button);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawButtonPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

class DrawButton2 {
    private static final int PREF_W = 200;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final int GAP = 20;
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 15f;
    private static final Stroke BASIC_STROKE = new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH);
    private static final Color COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color BG = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    private AbstractButton button = new JToggleButton();
    private int index;

    public DrawButton2(int index) {
        this.index = index;
        button.setBorderPainted(false);
        button.setBorder(null);
        button.setIcon(createPlainIcon());
        button.setSelectedIcon(createSelectedIcon());

        button.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    System.out.println("Index: " + index);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    private Icon createPlainIcon() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
        g2d.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    private Icon createSelectedIcon() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = img.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setStroke(BASIC_STROKE);
        g2d.setColor(BG);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, PREF_W, PREF_H);
        g2d.setColor(COLOR);
        g2d.drawOval(GAP, GAP, PREF_W - 2 * GAP, PREF_H - 2 * GAP);
        g2d.dispose();
        return new ImageIcon(img);
    }

    public AbstractButton getButton() {
        return button;
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawButton1 extends JToggleButton {
    private static final int PREF_W = 200;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final int GAP = 20;
    private static final float STROKE_WIDTH = 15f;
    private static final Stroke BASIC_STROKE = new BasicStroke(STROKE_WIDTH);
    private static final Color COLOR = Color.RED;
    private static final Color BG = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setStroke(BASIC_STROKE);
        if (!isSelected()) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
        } else {
            g2d.setColor(BG);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g2d.setColor(COLOR);
            g2d.drawOval(GAP, GAP, getWidth() - 2 * GAP, getHeight() - 2 * GAP);
        }
        g2d.dispose(); // since we created a new one
    }
}
```

Edited to show how to do this with JToggleButton and icons.

Comment: So you're just basically saying that I should create ImageIcon and pass it to a button? That sounds too simple... :D

Comment: @Mantas: I have edited the code to show you what I meant.